# Совместимость регулярок в Postgresql

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Сделал [тут](https://regex101.com/r/0A9OIs/1) регулярное выражение:

```
WHEN\s*'([^']*)'\s*THEN\s*\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*WHEN|ELSE\s*--nichts gefunden)
```

Вроде в доках написано, что в PostgreSQL поддерживается `(?=`, но почему-то до него всё работает правильно [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4270236d75658a4c724b9da2b734c4df), а с ним уже не работает вообще [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=81c9713e3f1e873587efe7d001eb3a4d)

что не так? и как поправить?

Comment: Вместо `[\s\S]` должно быть `.`. Да и вообще вам не нужен тут блок предварительного просмотра, замените `(?=\s*WHEN|ELSE\s*--nichts gefunden)` на `(?:\s*WHEN|ELSE\s*--nichts gefunden)`. В общем, `E'WHEN\\s*''([^'']*)''\\s*THEN\\s*\n(.*?)(?:\\s*WHEN|ELSE\\s*--nichts gefunden)'` + `'g'` (удалите ненужный флаг `m`) сработает.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  `.` вместо  `[\s\S]` это логично, так и было сначала, но в regex101 почему-то отказалось работать... Из-за `m` флага долго промучался)
Но ваша правка не делит результат, должно возвращаться 6 пар данных (как по первой ссылке), вместо одной

Comment: А, да, это я уже видел, попробуйте `E'WHEN\\s*?''([^'']*?)''\\s*?THEN\\s*?\n(.*?)(?:\\s*WHEN|ELSE\\s*--nichts gefunden)'`

Comment: а так получается через одну... именно для этого я и колдовал с предварительным просмотром... у нас начало и конец так получаются одинаковые, потому чётные блоки отфильтровывааются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT regexp_matches(
    (SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid) FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc WHERE proname iLIKE 'Auditlog__references__get'),
        E'WHEN\\s*?''([^'']*)''\\s*THEN\\s*\n(.*?)(?=\\s*WHEN|ELSE\\s*--nichts gefunden)',
        'g')
```

**Подробности**

- Шаблон `[\s\S]` не нужен, так как в PostgreSQL `.` находит любой символ, включая переход на новую строку
- Ленивый квантификатор после жадного (первого) на одном и том же "уровне" становится жадным, поэтому первый квантифицированный шаблон, `\s*?`, должен быть ленивым, чтобы все последующие тоже были ленивыми.
- Флаг `m` здесь не нужен (так как нет ни `^`, ни `$`), нужен только флаг `g` (чтобы найти все совпадения).

Comment: вот он где подводный камень то оказался, что ленивость игнорируется... Очень интересная особенность, в любом другом regexp синтаксисе ленивость после жадного вполне себе корректно переключается) Благодарю!